Documentary about South American teenagers suspected of committing a crime
I remember watching this documentary two years ago, maybe on YouTube, but I can't remember the name. 
The documentary was about a group of teenagers that were suspected of committing a crime. All of the evidence, however, indicates that they didn't commit the crime. From what I remember the teens come from somewhere in South America. During the documentary, they followed the entire court process. One of the teenagers was the main person that the court wanted to put in prison.
It is not any of the following:

Paradise Lost 
Central park 5 
Cropsey

Other important information:

Two years ago
Youtube maybe
Real life, in color, not a high production value, may have been
foreign


Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

Also, do you remember what crime they allegedly committed?


When: 2 years ago
Where: Youtube I believe.
Language: As I stated. I vaguely remember them being from South America but I could be wrong on this.
it was real life
yes it was in color (Not great quality however so it might be a foreign production as well)

What crime: No not specifically, I remember this one young who had it the worst out of all those involved (during court sessions, etc)

was everyone in the documentary from South America?  ie, did it take place in South America?  sorry if this seems obnoxious, but there's a big difference between the documentary being set in South America, and it being set somewhere else and the teens are from South America

also, since it might have been on youtube, have you tried looking through your viewing history (assuming you were logged in when you watched it)?

Could it be Give Up Tomorrow?
It’s not South America, however, the Philippines. 
About 7 teens stand accused in the murder of two sisters but the film is most focused on Paco Larrañaga. Was released 2011. 

You're a hero. I've been searching for this documentary for ages.
